# GL_INVALID_ENUM on glDrawElements

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I am calling `nglDrawElements` (`glDrawElements`) with the arguments `GL_TRIANGLES` (4), `GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT`, (amount of vertices, greater than 0), and 0. The error is for `GL_TRIANGLES`, saying 4 is an invalid type, but `glDrawArrays` works.
Code for `glDrawElements`:

```
nglDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, numVertices, 0);
```

Working code for `glDrawArrays`:

```
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, numVertices);
```

Why does nglDrawElements throw an error for GL_TRIANGLES?

Answer (score 1):

That's because you cofnused the second (`count`) and third (`type`) parameter, the prototype is

```
void glDrawElements(GLenum mode,
                    GLsizei count,
                    GLenum type,
                    const GLvoid * indices);
```

Comment: I'm an idiot, can't believe I spent 20 minutes on that. (thought my vertex count was 6 not 4)